# How to set thread exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

How to add thread exception for my code? For example if function fx (the first thread) is calculating more than 10 seconds.

```
e1 = threading.Event()
e2 = threading.Event()
e3 = threading.Event()

# init threads
t1 = threading.Thread(target=fx, args=(x, e1, e2))

t2 = threading.Thread(target=gx, args=(x, e2, e3))

t3 = threading.Thread(target=func, args=(e3, e1))

t1.start()

t2.start()

t3.start()

e1.set() #initiate the first event

t1.join()
t2.join()
t3.join()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider using the [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor) in `concurrent.futures` module instead of `threading.Thread`.
Example:

```py
e1 = threading.Event()
e2 = threading.Event()
e3 = threading.Event()

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:

    futures = {
        executor.submit(fx, x, e1, e2): 1,
        executor.submit(gx, x, e2, e3): 2,
        executor.submit(func, x, e3, e1): 3
    }

e1.set() #initiate the first event

for ft in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures, timeout=10):
    i = futures[ft]
    try:
        data = ft.result()
    except Exception as e:
        print('Call %d generated an exception: %s' % (i, e))
```

In this example all threads are limited to 10 seconds execution time. A TimeoutError is raised when getting the result of Future that has executed longer than 10 sec.

You can also put a time limit on the individual thread. Example:

```py
e1 = threading.Event()
e2 = threading.Event()
e3 = threading.Event()

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
    ft1 = executor.submit(fx, x, e1, e2)
    ft2 = executor.submit(gx, x, e2, e3)
    ft3 = executor.submit(func, x, e3, e1)

e1.set() #initiate the first event

try:
    data = ft1.result(timeout=10)
except Exception as e:
    print('Call generated an exception: %s' % e)
```

Comment: but how i can use e1, e2, e3  in your example if i don't use threading.Event()?